# Where do I put client code source files (JavaScript and CSS before minification etc.) in an asp.net 5 project?

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to have a src folder that contains all my client side code e.g. css, scripts, fonts, images etc. I want to use gulp to minify / combine some of these files and then copy the files into a dist folder. A folder structure typically looks something like this (outside of the .net world).

[image: Image taken from: https://css-tricks.com/whats-great-bower/]

I am now wondering how I can structure something like this in asp.net 5. Is wwwroot folder the same as the dist folder? or should I have both "src" and "dist" folders under the wwwroot folder?

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep client source file as a separate project. You can invoke glup build task to compile and copy compiled code into MVC project.

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872443/asp-net-mvc-5-separate-projects-for-ui-and-web) question before, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the folder where the web server serve public files from (web server root or public folder) is optional in asp.net 5. 
With the project templates that comes with visual studio this folder name is by default named to "wwwroot".
You change the name by modifying the property "webroot" in [project.json](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#webroot).

Its therefore possible to serve your public files from a folder named "dist". If you are using a project template in visual studio you can rename the "wwwroot" folder to "dist", just change the "webroot" property in project.json to "dist".

If you put your "dist" and "src" folders in a folder called "wwwroot" and this folder is specified as the "webroot" directory in project.json then both of these folders will be 
accessible via web requests. If you put the "src" folder outside the "wwwroot" folder then it will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

src folder should be outside wwwroot. wwwroot will replace the dist folder ( so replace it in gulp script). If you run the application from visual studio it will look for it there. You do not lose any gulp functionality even serve works from there. So using VS debug vs serve and browserlink/livereload etc is a matter of preference.

The below is just a sample of separate gulp tasks that work in Visual Studio. For demo purposes. Should help you get the idea and get started

```
    /*
This file in the main entry point for defining Gulp tasks and using Gulp plugins.
Click here to learn more. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518007
*/


var styleType = "SCSS"; // CSS/LESS

var wwwroot = 'wwwroot';

var gulp = require('gulp');

var del = require('del');

var debug = require('gulp-debug');


gulp.task('Clean:Delete', function () {
    del(wwwroot+"/*", '!web.config').then(paths => {
        console.log('Deleted files and folders:\n', paths.join('\n'));
    });
});


gulp.task('Copy:Fonts', function () {
    gulp.src(['src/fonts/**/*'], {
        base: 'src'
    })
      .pipe(debug())
      .pipe(gulp.dest( wwwroot ));
});

gulp.task('Copy:Images', function () {
    gulp.src(['src/images/**/*'], {
        base: 'src'
    })
      .pipe(debug())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(wwwroot));
});


gulp.task('Copy:HTML', function () {
    gulp.src(['src/html/**/*'], {
        base: 'src/html'
    })
      .pipe(debug())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(wwwroot+'/views'));
});
```

Tasks are listed in Task Runner Explorer and can be controlled from IDE again a matter of preference IDE vs CMD

For completion sake. Lately ther eis an emerging number of devs using Visual Studio Code for FrontEnd https://code.visualstudio.com/b?utm_expid=101350005-28.R1T8FshdTBWEfZjY0s7XKQ.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F